# Problem returning a libusb::Device from a function - attempting to return value referencing data owned by current function

Tags: rust, borrowing

I want to interface with a USB device so I'm using [libusb](https://crates.io/crates/libusb). I have a function that returns a `libusb::Device` of the device I am interested in:

```
pub fn obtain_device() -> Device<'static> {
    let context: Context = libusb::Context::new().unwrap();
    let option: Device = context
        .devices()
        .unwrap()
        .iter()
        .find(|d| d.device_descriptor().unwrap().vendor_id() == 0x0bda)
        .unwrap();
    option
}
```

However this does not compile:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `context`
  --> src/usb/mod.rs:19:5
   |
18 |     let option: Device = context.devices().unwrap().iter().find(|d| d.device_descriptor().unwrap().vendor_id() == 0x0bda).unwrap();
   |                          ------- `context` is borrowed here
19 |     option
   |     ^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

In my understanding it's the `context` object that it causing the issue even though that is not the object I return from the function. Looking at the definition of `libusb::Device`

```
/// A reference to a USB device.
pub struct Device<'a> {
    context: PhantomData<&'a Context>,
    device: *mut libusb_device,
}
```

It contains a reference to a `Context` which I assume is the cause of the compilation failure. But I am unsure of how I could return a `Device` from the function or am I not thinking correctly in how this should be coded. What if I want to pass the `Device` object to other functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the definition of [`Context::devices`](http://dcuddeback.github.io/libusb-rs/libusb/struct.Context.html#method.devices), the lifetime `'a` in `Device<'a>` is bound to the scope of the context, and will become invalid (i.e. would be a dangling pointer) if the `Context` goes out of scope. That is, the crate does not just wrap some pointer to a device that will live forever, but access the device "through" the context.

One way to deal with this would be to make the `Context` static, so it lives for the entire duration of your program. You can do that with `lazy_static`:

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use libusb::{Context, Device};

lazy_static! {
    static ref CONTEXT: Context = Context::new().unwrap();
}

pub fn obtain_device() -> Device<'static> {
    CONTEXT
        .devices()
        .unwrap()
        .iter()
        .find(|d| d.device_descriptor().unwrap().vendor_id() == 0x0bda)
        .unwrap()
}
```

You could also turn your function into a method of a struct, which owns the `Context`.

```
pub struct MyDeviceContext {
    context: libusb::Context,
}

impl MyDeviceContext {
    pub fn new(context: libusb::Context) -> Self {
        Self { context }
    }

    pub fn obtain_device(&self) -> Device<'_> {
        self.context
            .devices()
            .unwrap()
            .iter()
            .find(|d| d.device_descriptor().unwrap().vendor_id() == 0x0bda)
            .unwrap()
    }
}
```

The device lifetime is no longer `'static`, but is usable as long as the `MyDeviceContext` is still in scope.

Comment: Looks like I need to re-think how I would code things taking into account lifetimes of objects I am not immediately aware of being included in the object I actually want.